# Can perl Config::Simple module with properties file with variable assignment

Tags: perl

Can [Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aSimple) work with properties file with variable assignment, e.g.:

```
server_name=myapp.com
home_url=${server_name}/home/index.html
login_url=${server_name}/login/
```

Comment: One would expect someone who has written 62 posts to know how to format or at least how to look it up.

Comment: how should I forma this then?

Comment: I fixed the formatting when I posted that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything in the documentation about any templating ability, but nothing's stopping you from wrapping the Config::Simple object in order to treat the values as templates as you retrieve them.